# Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) - clear local storage and cookie on browser close

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, local-storage, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project that is a stand-alone SPA and calls API endpoints (with JWT if needed) to perform application functions.

This is how authentication is currently set up in my app: There is a user-validating API that I call when a user tries to sign in. Upon a successful sign-in, the API returns back to me a few pieces of information about the user (e.g., email, name, etc.) and a JWT. I store some of the user information in local storage and the JWT as a cookie.

There is an Authentication State Provider that I have wrapped around my project. The user's auth status is assessed by whether their user information is in the local storage and a cookie exists in the browser. Upon signing out, I clear out the local storage and the JWT cookie.

The issue that I have is this: If a user does not sign out, closes the browser, and opens it back up - they are still authenticated, even though that cookie is technically expired (e.g., after a day) and cannot be used anymore.

I do have an auto-timeout method, which essentially calls a JS function to clear out the local storage and JWT cookie upon 20 minutes or so of inactivity. But this doesn't control for cases where a user simply closes the browser without signing out properly.

--

I'm in dire need of help. Perhaps my authentication setup is entirely wrong, although lot of Blazor WASM tutorials online seem to have their auth system set up this way. I know Blazor Server can have auth set up in a different (perhaps better) way, but what is the best implementation for Blazor WASM?

An idea I had was clearing out the local storage and JWT cookie upon closing the browser. Is there a method for this? I.e., uponBrowserClose()

Or is this just a terrible idea?

Comment: Most apps do not clear authentication cookies when closing the browser. Instead, you should check the expiry on the cookie when the app loads and sign them out manually if it is expired before doing anything else. However, if you really want to sign out when the browser is closed, you're probably looking for the `window.onbeforeunload()` event.